# query all ES clusters statistics information under CCS mode

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, there are 3 clusters: cluster-1, cluster-2, cluster-3.
If we make a http request to cluster-1 like `GET ip:port/_cluster/stats`, only the information about cluster-1 returned as bellows:

```
"_nodes": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "cluster_name": "cluster-1",
    "cluster_uuid": "oiH4BeI3RPud6vc4pOnFGQ",
    "timestamp": 1699010346560,
    "status": "green",
    "indices": {
....
```

But can we get all clusters stats information with one request? I don`t find any useful information from ES official site.

Comment: Elasticsearch does not support a native way to retrieve statistics for multiple separate clusters with a single HTTP request. Use external cluster management and monitoring tools that can track multiple clusters and aggregate statistics in a centralized dashboard.